# Getting FastAPI request body in async exception handler, and publishing to GCP PubSub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have limited experience in using AsyncIO in Python, and am using Python's FastAPI framework.
For background, my application will be hosted on Google Cloud Run and is designed to receive a Cloud PubSub notification (from a Cloud Storage bucket), validate the message, and then process a file from Cloud Storage, sending the individual contents on to another PubSub Topic.

The application is pretty much working end to end, but I have a feature whereby if a message fails validation, or I'm unable to process the file in some way, I want to send the notification's whole contents to a PubSub dead letter topic I've also set up.

My problem is that the exception handler (included below) that I want to use to send this dead letter queue message onto PubSub is not working. It seems to go as far as when I call "await request.json()` which has to be awaited because the source code has the json() method as a coroutine, so I can't call it synchronously to get the data.

Here's a sample of my code (`main.py`):

```py
app = FastAPI(title=settings.api_name)

pubsub = PubSubPublisher()

@app.post("/v1/file-processing", response_model=dict)
def download_and_process(request: PubSubRequest):
    """Main response method"""
    logger.info(f"Received message {request.message.messageId}")
    file_upload_event = unmarshal_message(request.message)
    logger.info(f"Processing file {file_upload_event.name}")
    file = MyFileClass()
    messages = file.process()
    pubsub.publish_message_batch(app_config.topic_id, messages)


@app.exception_handler(DeadLetterError)
async def dead_letter_handler(request: Request, exc: DeadLetterError):
    """Function to handle an exception requiring the sending of a message to the Dead Letter topic"""
    logger.error(f"Sending to Dead Letter Queue. Reason: {exc}")
    message_content = await request.json()
    logger.error("Building DLQ message")  # TODO remove
    dlq_message = base64.b64decode(message_content["message"]["data"]).decode('utf-8')
    logger.error("send to pubsub")  # TODO remove
    app.pubsub.publish_message_to_pubsub(app_config.dead_letter_topic, dlq_message)
    logger.error("Sending response")  # TODO remove
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": str(exc)})
    )
```

In the logs, I can see the first logging call "Sending to Dead Letter Queue. Reason:...", But I can't see the other logs I've put in there, which leads me to assume the `await request.json()` is the problem here.
But how else do I get the original request's content if not through that? My experiences with Async code before led me to believe that this should be possible.

***TL;DR***
in FastAPI, I can't retrieve the original message content in a custom exception handler using a mixture of sync and async code. Using a line of async code seems to stop processing in place. Why is this? And what can be done if I need to publish this message content onward using synchronous code to PubSub?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your requirements by giving a bit more details about how you are processing and validating the messages? Here is an example [code](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#python) to asynchronously publish messages.You can also take a look at these [link1](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) and [link2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asyncio-in-python/) also.